# Give the proper negation of the statement: If x is any integer (I think thats the set) "If x^2 is odd and 2x+1 is prime then x is prime."

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Give the proper negation of the statement: 
If x is any integer (I think thats the set)

"If x^2 is odd and 2x+1 is prime then x is prime."

Comment: The negation of "if $p$, then $q$" is "$p$ and not $q$".

Comment: so it would be "x^2 is odd and 2x+1 is prime, and x is not prime."

Comment: Strange statement: $x=9$ has $x^2$ odd, $2x+1=19$ prime, but $x$ not prime.

Answer (score 0):

x is composite and x is odd and 2x+1 is prime.

Comment: can you explain where you got that?

Comment: @Yeuhhh I thought about it. If x is prime then it is implied by anything. Thus we have x is not prime. But the implication needs the hypothesis to be true for it to be false. x is composite and x is odd (x^2 is odd).

Comment: so that would follow if "p, then q" is "p and not q"

Comment: @Yeuhhh yes; do you see why that's what makes sense? If you are saying p does not imply q this means you can have p but not have q. In math things can happen only if they do happen, so this is just p and not q.

Comment: so p implies q so the negation is having p still happen but q not happen, so wouldnt it be " x squared is still odd and 2x+1 is still prime but x is composite.

Comment: pretty sure thats what you just said.

Comment: @Yeuhh Yeah that sounds good.